# How to get the http status code in custom HandleErrorAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a custom HandleErrorAttribute which is applied globally by being registered in the filters. The problem is, I can't catch the proper http error code. Every time it is 200 code inside that attribute.

```
public class HandleAndLogErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
            return;
        var statusCode = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode; //always 200
        LogManager.Error(filterContext.Exception);

        filterContext.Result = CreateActionResult(filterContext, statusCode);
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }

    protected virtual ActionResult CreateActionResult(ExceptionContext filterContext, int statusCode)
    {
        var ctx = new ControllerContext(filterContext.RequestContext, filterContext.Controller);
        var statusCodeName = ((HttpStatusCode)statusCode).ToString();
        var viewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml";
        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
        var result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = viewName,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
        };
        result.ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try getting the status code by new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Going through the source code for [HandleErrorAttribute.cs](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HandleErrorAttribute.cs), it looks like you can get the status code using the below code

```
var statusCode = new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode();
```